# Plot specific column values in Seaborn instead of every column value

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, filtering, seaborn

I can't figure out how to filter a column and then plot it successfully on Seaborn.

The below code works perfectly and plots a line graph with all of the unique columns values separated.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

sns.set(style='darkgrid')
data = wcsales1.loc[wcsales1.Sales_Year > 2016]
sales_year = data['Sales_Year']
ppa = data['Price_Per_Acre']
dates = data['LATEST_LAND_SALE_DATE']
juris = data['PLANNING_JURISDICTION']

sns.relplot(x = sales_year, y = ppa, ci=None, kind='line', hue=juris)
plt.show()
```

However, I want to plot the values in the variable 'egs', listed below, which are two of many unique values in the variable 'juris'

I tried the below code but am getting a Value Error, also included below.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

sns.set(style='darkgrid')
data = wcsales1.loc[wcsales1.Sales_Year > 2016]
data = data.reset_index()
sales_year = data['Sales_Year']
ppa = data['Price_Per_Acre']
dates = data['LATEST_LAND_SALE_DATE']
juris = data['PLANNING_JURISDICTION']
egs = ['HS', 'FV']
south = data.loc[data.PLANNING_JURISDICTION.isin(egs)]
print(type(south))

sns.relplot(x = sales_year, y = ppa, ci=None, kind='line', hue=south)
plt.show()
```

Error below

```
Shape of passed values is (19, 3), indices imply (1685, 3)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: please show the plots that you have done

Comment: filter the data set based on your required columns 
`data[(data.column==value1) & (data.column==value2)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `sns` you should pass the data option and `x,y, hue` as the columns in the data:

```
sns.relplot(x='Sales_Year', y='Price_Per_Acre',
            hue='PLANNING_JURISDICTION',
            data=data.loc[data.PLANNING_JURISDICTION.isin(egs)],
            kind='line', ci=None
           )
```